# web services and namespaces in schemas

Tags: xsd, xml-namespaces

What is the true purpose of the namespace in technologies such as web services? I can understand in something like XHTML where it's potentially used by the browser to determine the intended rendering mode, but these URL styled schemas seem to be used in a multitude of places, not all of which make sense to me?

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xml-namespaces/info?

Comment: Thanks John, starting to get the picture. I still think there's a little bit more to it, but I think with what I've read, I'll be able to go and do some digging to get a better answer.